# Go unmarshal JSON to struct with nil values

Tags: go

I am trying to write a rest endpoint to update a resource but struggling with parsing JSON and then unmarshaling it to a struct.

Let's say this is my struct:

```
type Car struct {
  Make string `json:"make"`
  Model string `json:"model"`
  Mileage int `json:"mileage"`
  Dealer string `json:"Dealer"`
}
```

I know that I could make the types pointers to avoid this issue by the way, but then that breaks my JSON responses where `nil` turns into `null`

Anyway, let's say an update call is made but the json from the client is

```
{
  "dealer": "Jim's Cars"
}
```

If I unmarshal this incoming JSON against `car Car`, then `car.Mileage` will be 0.

This is an issue when it comes time to do an update on the database side because I don't want to update the mileage to 0.

Is there a way to do ensure that if the user didn't send `mileage` that `car.Mileage` is not 0?

Comment: Use pointers for all fields that may be missing from the input JSON.

Comment: @icza if I use pointer, then how can I return json with fields that are not `null` but instead `""`

Comment: Simply initialize the pointer field with a pointer pointing to `""`.